# Getting cron logs to add to file, not override it

Tags: linux, ssh, cron

First, I'm sorry if this is the wrong stackexchange for this, but it seemed like the right one.

This is my crontab right now:

```
MAILTO=****@gmail.com
10,30,50 * * * * ~/webapps/****/apache2/bin/start
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/****/WR/cron.py > ~/webapps/****/WR/cron.log 2>&1
```

But every time the output is placed into the cron.log file, all the old content gets overridden. How do I stop that? Or, if it's not possible, what's an alternative?

Note: The `****` in the URL and email are there to hide personal information.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Swap `>` for `>>`.

```
>  = write to file, overwriting what was already there
>> = append to file, create if it doesn't exist
```

i.e.:

```
MAILTO=****@gmail.com
10,30,50 * * * * ~/webapps/****/apache2/bin/start
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/****/WR/cron.py >> ~/webapps/****/WR/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Where are you getting all this formatting information from?  My webhost's cPanel has like 0 formatting information posted for crontab commands.  Only the `>/dev/null 2>&1` trick.